# DropDown TypeMOde on select value Change from Database

Tags: json, hibernate, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a drop down list called is as TypeMode,in that drop down list i have 1)In 2)out 3)Internal

in the jsp page i have From texbox followed by a search button and other text box fields.
when i type an ID in the Search box and click search the other text box fields should be fetched frm database.

i have one more TO texbox followed by Search button and other text box fields,when i type an iD in the search box and press the search button ,other values shuld be fetched form database .

Now the the problem is ,as i said that i have DropDown list called TypeMode.
when   i select any they as In or Out....From texbox and and To Textbox search depends on that.

for Example i have selected "In" as the TYpeMode,
when i type an Id in the From Text box search ,only spefic value should fetch from database,
but in To search box search all the values should come.

For example on Select "Out "as typeMode,
From texbox search should fetch all the values ,and TO search box should search only specifc values .

Answer (score 0):

Sir you can do it just by doing post back to that form 
** if you dont want the page to refresh put the other text boxes in a updatePanel (dont forget to include the "script manager" )
** or you can easily to make your page more systematic you can use PM or jQuery ajax and send them the values of DDL and the ID

Comment: since  i am new to ajax and jquery can u give me any example...boss...that will be usefull..

Comment: Sir i advice to spend some time on jQuery and specially jQuery.Ajax

check this link and follow :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-i7OS3AkMk

Comment: wht i have done is i have written a query for the id ,when i user enters the id,it will fetch all the data..and in jstl i have taken the respected values which i wanted in hidden field and passed those values through jquery,..i knw this is a bad way....can u suggest any other with clear explanation...plzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "test.html?SEND_YOUR_DATA_AS_QUERY_STRINGS!!",
  success: function(RESULT){
    alert(RESULT);//here put the values in the appropriate textboxes
  }
});

///while the URL is a page of your creation that replies with only the result of your query